# Indentation in Table of Contents & TOC Line Spacing

Tags: table-of-contents

1. Hey guys, **I am trying to indent everything after 'Chapter' in the TOC but nothing before it.** How can this be done? I have searched endlessly for a solution, several solutions mention going to 'memoir' document class, but this is a thesis and must conform to 'Chicago style'.

Also, **the line spacing is different for subsections, can they be all uniform?**

Attached is a stripped down version of what I have and is basically a collection of what I have found on the web to try and please the publisher to their constraints.

[image: help]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[papersize={8.5in,11in}, top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.25in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{setspace}

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftaftertoctitle{\hfill\null\\\null\hfill\textbf{PAGE}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
%\setlength{\cftsecindent}{2em}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{2em}

\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftafterloftitle{\hfill\null\\\null\hfill\textbf{PAGE}}

\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftafterlottitle{\hfill\null\\\null\hfill\textbf{PAGE}} 

\newlength{\largNum}
\newlength{\tocRightMargin} % Marge droite
\setlength{\tocRightMargin}{2cm}

\newlength{\tocLeftMarginSecondLineFigure}
\setlength{\tocLeftMarginSecondLineFigure}{5em}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure[2]{%
  \settowidth{\largNum}{#2}%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip .10em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{3.4em}%
        \noindent
    \begingroup
      \def\numberline##1{\makebox[\tocLeftMarginSecondLineFigure][l]{\figurename\ ##1}}%
      \pretolerance=10000
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \tocRightMargin
      \parfillskip -\tocRightMargin
     \leavevmode \normalsize
     \advance\leftskip \tocLeftMarginSecondLineFigure
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak
       \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hskip 1\tocRightMargin plus 1fil\nobreak
        \hb@xt@\largNum{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother
%
\newlength{\tocLeftMarginSecondLineTable}
\setlength{\tocLeftMarginSecondLineTable}{4.5em}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@table[2]{%
  \settowidth{\largNum}{#2}%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip .10em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{3.4em}%
        \noindent
    \begingroup
      \def\numberline##1{\makebox[\tocLeftMarginSecondLineTable][l]{\tablename\ ##1}}%
      \pretolerance=10000
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \tocRightMargin
      \parfillskip -\tocRightMargin
     \leavevmode \normalsize
     \advance\leftskip \tocLeftMarginSecondLineTable
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak
       \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hskip 1\tocRightMargin plus 1fil\nobreak
        \hb@xt@\largNum{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}

\doublespacing
\thispagestyle{empty}
 \newpage

\pagestyle{myheadings}
 \setcounter{page}{1}
 \pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{center}
                                                % TITLE PAGE
\textbf{AN INVESTIGATION INTO ...}
\\[.25in]
\vspace*{2cm}\noindent\rule{3cm}{0.4pt}
\\[.25in]
A Thesis\\ Presented to the\\ Faculty of\\ Blah University
\\[.25in]
\noindent\rule{3cm}{0.4pt}
\\[.25in] 
In Partial Fulfillment\\ of the Requirements for the Degree \\ Master of Science\\ in\\ Mechanical Engineering
\\[.25in]
\noindent\rule{3cm}{0.4pt}
\\[.25in]
by\\ Thomas L. Murray\\Fall 2014

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
                                                % SIGNATURES PAGE
\textbf{SAN DIEGO STATE UNIVERSITY}
\\[.3in]
The Undersigned Faculty Committee Approves the \\ Thesis of Thomas L. Murray
\\[.3in]
An Investigation Into The Control Of A Vehicle Suspension \\ Using Model Reference Adaptive Control \\ With Voice Coil Actuators\\[.5in]
\singlespacing
\vspace*{.5in}
\noindent\rule{3.5in}{0.4pt}
\\ Kee Moon, Chair\\Department of Mechanical Engineering
\\[.3in]
\noindent\rule{3.5in}{0.4pt}
\\ Fletcher Miller\\Department of Mechanical Engineering
\\[.3in]
\noindent\rule{3.5in}{0.4pt}
\\ Gustaaf Jacobs\\Department of Aerospace Engineering
\\[.3in]
\noindent\rule{3.5in}{0.4pt}
\\ George Mansfield, Co-Chair\\Department of Mechanical Engineering
\\[.3in]
\vspace*{1cm}\noindent\rule{3.5in}{0.4pt}
\\ Approval Date
%
\pagenumbering{roman}
\doublespacing
\setcounter{page}{2}
\clearpage
                                                % COPYRIGHT PAGE
\vspace*{2.5in}
\begin{center}
Copyright \copyright \hspace{2mm}2014\\by\\Thomas L. Murray\\All Rights Reserved
\end{center}
                                                % SPECIAL THANKS
\clearpage
\textbf{DEDICATION}
\\[2in]
\begin{center}\vspace{3cm} To my father, may his soul be greeted by God.\\ 
To my mother for urging excellence incessantly.\end{center}
\clearpage
                                                % QUOTATION
\vspace*{2.5in}
{\singlespacing Everything should be as simple as possible, no simpler {\\ \vspace{-.3cm} \hfill -Albert Einstein }}
                                                % ABSTRACT
\clearpage
\begin{center}
\textbf{ABSTRACT OF THESIS} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{ABSTRACT OF THESIS}
\singlespacing
An Investigation into the ... \\by\\Thomas L. Murray\\Master of Science in Mechanical Engineering\\Blah University, 2014
\end{center}
\raggedright\singlespacing
\hspace*{1cm}The control of a vehicle suspension is of great interest to control engineers due to its classic model structure, vibratory modes, and response. Despite being such a widely studied system, most vehicle suspensions today still employ passive suspensions comprised of mechanical springs and dampers. This investigation is conducted to determine the feasibility and value of using model reference adaptive control in combination with voice coil (linear motor) actuators. In particular, voice coils are well known for their low hysteresis, and with the use of an appropriate controller may be able to improve ride quality along stretches of road when encountering small signal disturbances as is typical of highways and city streets where road frequencies are varied and are have an RMS value 0.17 inches (0.43 cm) in amplitude. Substantially improved results can occur using MRAC over classical control methods when the Laplace transform plant is substituted by the full simulation to obtain states, especially when MRAC and a tuned PID controller are used in concert. When acceleration control is used with MRAC, ride comfort is improved drastically, however the control effort required to maintain such control is extensive.
%
                                                % TABLE OF CONTENTS
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
                                                % TABLE OF TABLES
\clearpage
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{LIST OF TABLES}
                                                % TABLE OF FIGURES
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\clearpage
                                                % ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\normalsize{\textbf{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}}
\vspace*{-1cm}
\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{CHAPTER}
\raggedright

\hspace*{1cm} I would like to thank God for his countless blessings. \\
I would like to thank my advisor, Professor George Mansfield, who has poured his wisdom and knowledge into my vessel until it was overflowing. I appreciate the times we were able to sit down and discuss the work, that it may be good.  I would like to thank his wife, Margaret, for allowing me to borrow him. \\
\hspace*{1cm} I would like to give a special thanks to Chis Yates and George Mansfield of Continental Controls for allowing me to use the solid model of their voice coil, voice coil parts and assemblies and any specifications related to the device. \\
\hspace*{1cm} I am thankful for all the professors who have aided me in this work. Professor Afshaw Beyene for providing such wonderful guidance navigating the graduate world.  To the committee members for hearing this work be presented and defended including Professors Gustav Jacobs,  Fletcher Miller and Kee Moon. \\
%

\clearpage
                                                % THESIS START - INTRODUCTION 
 \setcounter{page}{1}
 \pagenumbering{arabic}

% page 1 %
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{A Brave New World}
 \hspace*{1cm} Control engineering is a necessity these days with the continuous advancement of technology in our developing world.  As systems become more complex, and processes become more demanding, the control of output of such systems becomes increasingly critical.  We do not just need controls in our world, we require them. Not merely to remove the drudgery of operating a manual repetitive process, nor as a matter of convenience to automatically brew our coffee before we wake.  We require them everyday to control complex systems such as a heart defibrillator to keep a heart pumping, optimizing power consumption in electrical grids, and determining caution levels for alerts to disastrous weather systems. \\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tkae a look at the `titlesec/titletoc` package (§ 6 of the documentation).

Comment: I have poured over the titlesec/titletoc package documentation for several hours for the past day and half. The entire document sounds very related to what I want to do, but I don't really understand how to use the document to my advantage to find a solution.

Comment: The problem comes comes from the fact that your ‘CHAPTER’ and the like are sections in the article class. You probably should use a class with true chapters, like report.

Comment: You've used the wrong class here: you want chapters which `article` doesn't have. It's not clear why you've done that, which for me makes this unclear as a concept even though what you want to get out is obvious!